# Is there a limit to the number of <li> elements in an <ul>?

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm loading in a collection of 343 objects into a `BackboneCollection` it's `fetch()` method.

Those 343 objects are templated into `<li>`elements.

I would expect 343 elements to be displayed on the page, but `$('#myapp li').length` tells me that only 200 objects are there.

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Do you see the same count in all browsers?

Comment: Have you counted the elements by hand (i.e. does `.length` give a wrong value or does backbone not actually insert more than 200 elements)?

Comment: This must be Backbone related or a coding fault. As far as I know there is no limit to any kind of HTML element in the DOM.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the W3C spec says nothing about the maximum number of list items in any given list. Nor is there a maximum for nested lists as well.

Comment: I think the back end is just returning 200 elements. _Those 343 objects are templated into `<li>`elements._ Did you validate this? I think it is just 200 elements that are getting templated.

Comment: There's no limit in HTML to how many LI's can be inside a single UL . [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cUVVP/1/), so it must be the backend limiting the output somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is *not* a limit to how many `<li>` elements a DOM will allow.

I create an example in which you can create `<li>` elements dynamically.
Put in an integer value, as you can see it's the same in all browsers.
I tested with values up to 1000 across all browsers.

[Check out this example](http://jsfiddle.net/qEFBG/)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I debugged more throughly and discovered a plugin that was truncating my `<li>`s at 200 elements.